# How to delete an Arrow in Joint JS Library?

Tags: javascript

I've the following challenge, when a user selects an Arrow and press delete 
key, I must clear the arrow. The arrow will be always related to 2 
State's; when the user fires the event, I wanna know which States 
(start and end) the arrow is related to, and wanna clear it from the 
view. How can I do that?